# getting ENOENT Error when extracting the path of an image in S3 Bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My requirement is to `resize` an image present in `s3 bucket` by **50%**. I found an npm package named [lwip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lwip#open-an-image) which does image resizing for local images.

My code is as follows

```
var lwip=require('lwip');
lwip.open(imagePath //Format of the path is as follows "https://s3bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.jpg"
, function (err, image) {
        if (err) {
            //error handling
        } else{
         //Some logic for resizing the image
       }
   });
```

I am getting the following error

```
ENOENT, open 'https://s3bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.jpg'
```

Can Somebody help with this issue as I am unable to understand why I am getting this error?

I have also made my s3 bucket as public so that anybody can use the image paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass the S3 URL of an image, i.e. a remote file. lwip works with local files.

Instead, you need to:

- copy the file from S3 on to your local disk
- perform any resizing operations
- upload the resized file to S3

... or use a module that supports resizing directly on S3.

ENOENT just means "file does not exist", which is correct.

Comment: Hey Mike is going there a way to create multiple images  of the same image of different scales before uploading to s3 bucket. Can you suggest me some npm modules for it?

Comment: I'm not really a heavy node user, so I can't recommend any npm modules for this. Thumbor, a Python application, can do a lot of cool stuff. It's like an image manipulation server, and integrates with S3.